# IAP access token with Gmail API

Tags: angular, flask, gmail-api, google-api-js-client, google-iap

I have the following Error

> google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: The credentials do not contain the necessary fields need to refresh the access token. You must specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.

My project is built with Angular front side and flask.
My web app is protected with IAP with `Gmail.readonly` scope ( I need to list all labels for the user).

So I need to get the access_token from IAP oauth2 and pass it to the back for call Gmail API
Angular side I try to get my access_token with this

Init gapi

```
 async initGoogleAuth(): Promise<void> {
    const payload = new Promise((resolve) => {
      gapi.load('auth2', resolve);
    });
    return payload.then(async () => {
      await gapi.auth2
        .init({
          client_id: this.clientId,
          fetch_basic_profile: true,
          prompt: 'select_account'
        })
        .then(auth => {
          this.gapiSetup = true;
          this.authInstance = auth;
        });
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log('Error initiating Google auth');
      console.log(e);
      return;
    });
  }
```

authenticate if gapi is init

```
async authenticate(): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.gapiSetup) {
      await this.initGoogleAuth();
    }

    const signInInstance = this.authInstance.signIn();
    await signInInstance.then(result => {
      const googleUser = this.authInstance.currentUser.get();
      this.isSignedIn = googleUser.isSignedIn();
      const profile = this.authInstance.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile()
      localStorage.setItem('email', profile.getEmail());
      localStorage.setItem('userName', profile.getName());
      localStorage.setItem('imageUrl', profile.getImageUrl());
      localStorage.setItem('token', this.authInstance.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().id_token);
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', this.authInstance.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token);
      console.log(this.authInstance.currentUser.get().getAuthResponse(true))
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }
```

From my component, I  pass through header access_toke

```
 sendRequest() {
    const headers = {
      headers: {
        "x-dvtm-access-token": localStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
        "x-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email": localStorage.getItem('email')
      }
    };
    // add "/check-preserve" for prod
    this.httpClient.get(environment.apiUrl + "/check-preserve", headers).subscribe(res => {
      if (typeof res === "string") {
        this.processResult(JSON.parse(res))
      }
      console.log(typeof (res));
      this.loading = false
    }, err => {
      this.loading = false
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
```

Flask side I get the token here and build credentials :

```
access_token = request.headers.get('x-dvtm-access-token')
user = request.headers.get('X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email').replace("accounts.google.com:", "")

if not access_token or not user:
    return "Not authorized", 401



creds = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(access_token)
logging.info(creds.__dict__)
response = check_preserve_label(creds, user=user)
```

What I am missing? thank you

```
            EDIT
```

SO I change my flask to send   HTTP request via (requests module) and add header Authorization : .
But  I have the feeling that IAP oauth2 do not provide scope access ( even if is set on configuration)

> 'error': {'code': 403, 'message': 'Request had insufficient
> authentication scopes.', 'errors': [{'message': 'Insufficient
> Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason':
> 'insufficientPermissions'}], 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}

SO I might need a double authentication Once for IAP ( domain access) and other for scope access ( Gmail for me )  source [Issue traker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162720785)

Comment: Access tokens are only good for one hour. Your code is trying to refresh the access token using a refresh token but it doesnt have one.   Try digging around in the auth section here https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs It might help

Comment: Okey, but when i connect first time with the app ( cache and cookie cleanup) its a new access_token and google.oauth2.credentials is supposed to work with just access_token

Comment: It does work with just the access_token for an hour,  then either your going to have to force the user to login again or you are going to have to use a refresh token.